# Next.js Error: async/await Not Supported in React Client Component Despite No Usage - 'use client' Causing Issue"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, runtime-error, react-context

For simplicity, I have this useState function

```
    'use client'
    import {useState} from 'react';
    
    const Home = () => {
      const [juice, setJuice] = useState('apple');
      return (
        <div className='w-full flex flex-col lg:flex-row h-40 bg-black' onClick={() => setJuice('orange')}>
          <p className='text-white text-2xl font-bold ml-4 mt-4'>{juice}</p>
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    export default Home
```

This works fine, when I click the div, the text display changes.

Then when I import this specific component, useState no longer works

```
    'use client'
    
    import ManageOrders from '../components/manage_orders';
    
    import {useState} from 'react';
    
    const Home = () => {
      const pageType = 'manageOrders';
      const [juice, setJuice] = useState('juice');
      return (
        <div>
            <div className='w-full flex flex-col lg:flex-row h-40 bg-black' onClick={() => setJuice('orange')}>
            <p className='text-white text-2xl font-bold ml-4 mt-4'>{juice}</p>
            </div>
            <ManageOrders />
        </div>
      )
    }
    
    export default Home
```

Now when using useState, I get this next.js error.

***Error: async/await is not yet supported in Client Components, only Server Components. This error is often caused by accidentally adding `'use client'` to a module that was originally written for the server.***

Within that component, is a datatable that is created with an await function.

```
    export default async function ManageOrdersDataTable() {
      const data = await getData()
     
      return (
        <div className="w-full mx-auto py-10">
          <DataTable columns={columns} data={data} />
        </div>
      )
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to fetch the data properly with useEffect inside the ManageOrdersDataTable component.

```
    export default function ManageOrdersDataTable() {
        const [data, setData] = useState([]);
      
        useEffect(() => {
          const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await getData();
            setData(result);
          };
      
          fetchData();
        }, []);
      
        return (
          <div className="w-full mx-auto py-10">
            <DataTable columns={columns} data={data} />
          </div>
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't recreate the issue. [Github](https://github.com/ArnasDickus/stack-overflow-77732690) [Live Version](https://stack-overflow-77732690.vercel.app/). Everything works fine on my end. The issue might be with how you use PageProvider. Here's my setup:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main>
      <PageProvider>
        <AdminMenu />
      </PageProvider>
    </main>
  );
}
```

*OUTDATED answer*

It seems that your usePage component is server side. And useContext is supported on client side. [next-redux-docs](https://vercel.com/guides/react-context-state-management-nextjs). As well as you can't import server side component to client side.

Adding use client in usePage component should fix the error.

Comment: Apologies, I left out the 'use client' line and have updated the question.

Comment: @TheHalfTimePrince I updated the answer. So far I don't think your presented code is an issue.

Comment: I woke up this morning realising I had completely missed the real issue. I updated the question to make it more clear, its a very simple fix that should've been obvious to me. Thanks for the help.